# How do I retrieve number data from a javascript data object?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to retrieve the numbers from the javascript variables, however, I was getting a 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined' error.

```
var myData1 = [{'x': 0.18448749856020055, 'y': 0.1824}];
var myData2 = [{'x': 0.16848208075388948, 'y': 0.20390119271867582}];

var testing = myData1.x[0];
console.log(testing);
```

Comment: its `myData1[0].x;` (as `myData` is an array[] of things with a `.x`)

Comment: @AlexK. Thank you very much! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

`myData1` is an array of objects.

`myData1[0]` will get the first element of the array which is an object.

By `myData1[0].x` you can access the value corresponding to the key `x` of the object.

```js
var myData1 = [{'x': 0.18448749856020055, 'y': 0.1824}];
var myData2 = [{'x': 0.16848208075388948, 'y': 0.20390119271867582}];

var testing = myData1[0].x;
console.log(testing);
```